# How can I create a shortcut to "Foo" without " - Shortcut" suffix?

Tags: windows-vista, shortcuts

Whenever I create a shortcut to a file or folder in Vista, I'd like it to not automatically append " - Shortcut" to the name of the shortcut.

For example:

1. Create a shortcut to the "Foo" application.
2. Shortcut gets named "Foo - Shortcut".
3. I then have to manually remove the " - Shortcut" from the name.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid having to do step #3 every time I make a shortcut.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Microsoft has not released a Vista specific version of TweakUI, but Microsoft MVP Ramesh Kumar has written an unofficial one called [Ultimate Windows Tweaker](http://www.winvistaclub.com/Ultimate_Windows_Tweaker.html) that can do what you want in a user-friendly way (ie no registry hacking). The option you want is under *Additional Tweaks -> Remove “-Shortcut to”…*

Comment: And for Windows XP indeed, TweakUI has this option (if a XP user was checking this question..)

Comment: Actually, I had originally included a link to TweakUI XP. But this question is in reference specifically to the Vista version, which uses a different label in the shortcut: “- Shortcut” instead of “Shortcut to”. So I ended up deleting that part of the answer. I guess I could roll-back.

Comment: No, I think it's good like this, the main answer is about the question, under Vista, so. The XP fact is more matching to the simple comment.

Comment: UWT also works for **Windows 7** and is available from *The Windows Club* in addition to Ramesh’s site.

Answer (score 15):

There's a simple registry hack you can do for this, which I've provided a downloadable reg hack file for. It says Vista, but it should work across the board.

[Remove "Shortcut" Text From New Shortcuts in Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/remove-shortcut-text-from-new-shortcuts-in-vista/)

[image]

Comment: I think I linked to your solution in another question as well ;-)