# Prevent "- Shortcut" suffix when creating shortcuts on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry

Some superuser [answers](https://superuser.com/questions/18846/how-to-create-shortcut-to-foo-without-shortcut-suffix) and many other Google hits show that setting `link` to `00 00 00 00` for the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\` 
will stop concatenating the suffix `- Shortcut` when shortcuts are created.

I'm using Windows 7 and this has not worked for me. I have tried

- manually setting the key,
- using `Ultimate Windows Tweaker`
- and running a `.reg` file,

but none have worked.

I have set the value, created the shortcut, noted the `- Shortcut` suffix and checked that the regkey value was still `00 00 00 00`. The value persists across reboots. Could all those references really be wrong, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that a reboot was all that was necessary for the tweak to start working. Indeed, setting the value to `00 00 00 00` did it. Maybe a reboot was more than necessary, and just killing and restarting `explorer.exe` would have done it.

Comment: @Tim_Partridge Mark your answer as accepted. This way other users can see that an official answer exists

Answer (score 3):

The procedure as described above with setting the `String` Value of `Link` to all zero did not work for me. Even after restart, the suffix `- shortcut` was still there. Sometimes, it also happened that the `Link` String Value was reset to e.g. 16. However, I found an alternative that worked for my Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit. Here is the trick:

1. Open the registry editor: Start Menu » Run » regedit
2. Save (export) a copy of the current registry – just in case of a mistake. Best is to save it on the desktop and give it a name with the date and some explanation that describes when you saved this copy (e.g. "20120319 registry before removing shortcut suffix")
3. Then, you navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\`
4. If there is a key called "NamingTemplates" already, then you may enter a new string value directly and skip the next step #5.
5. If there is no such key called "NamingTemplates", create this key under the above path. To do so, left-click on "Explorer" in the above path, then right-click in the right half of the window and select new >> key. Rename the key to "NamingTemplates". The complete path is then: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\NamingTemplates`
6. Now, under the key "NamingTemplates" you create a String Value with the name "ShortcutNameTemplate" (without the quotes). To do so, left-click on the key "NamingTemplates" and then make a right-click in the right half of the window. Select new >> string value. Rename the String Value to "ShortcutNameTemplate". For this, you need to right-click on the String Value and select >> Rename.
7. Then, you right-click once again on the newly created String Value, select >> Modify and enter the value "%**s**.lnk" (again without the quotes).
8. Exit and close the registry editor
9. Then, for the change to take effect, close the Exit Windows Explorer and open it again. Now, the "-shortcut" suffix is gone.

Here is also the screenshot how it should look like after the changes:
[image: Registry after the changes to suppress the "-shortcut" suffix in Windows 7]

If later on, you need to reverse the change:

- If you had to create the key "NamingTemplates" -> then, just delete this key to make the change undone
- If the key was already there, then you should set its value back to the original value, before the change (i.e. you should keep record...)

Comment: There's an error here. You wrote *...setting the `String` Value of `Link`...*. The "string" data type is wrong. Instead [Microsoft says that the `Link` value must be of type `REG_BINARY`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/253212). Just tested it. Works.

Comment: Is there a placeholder for the file / folder name without extension? I would prefer to have a link named "Document" instead of "Document.odt" for example. String worked for me.

Comment: Changing the value for the current user seems more appropriate: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\NamingTemplates`. It takes effect when Windows Explorer is restarted for the current user.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting Explorer is sufficient, there's no need to reboot.

Open the Start Menu, find a blank area and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> whilst right clicking there. Choose the *Exit Explorer* option.

Comment: For the record: in earlier Windows versions, close Explorer through *Start - Turn Off* (or *Start - Shut Down*), then hold Ctrl+Alt+Shift and click Cancel.

Comment: This procedure to stop Explorer is unclear to me. Right clicking with modifier keys does nothing. On the contrary Windows Explorer can be restarted using the [Task Manager](https://www.howtogeek.com/66622/stupid-geek-tricks-6-ways-to-open-windows-task-manager/).

Answer (score 1):

[The Windows Club](http://www.thewindowsclub.com)'s Ultimate Windows Tweaker ([direct](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-v2-a-tweak-ui-for-windows-7-vista) or via [search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=ultimate+windows+tweaker+for+windows+7)) did the trick for me on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.  I simply checked its *Remove "-Shortcut" suffix for new shortcuts* option under Additional Tweaks.

Comment: True, @sim: I updated my answer to at least deal with the possibility that the specific, direct link I provided to UWT no longer resolves.  Of course, if UWT simply isn't available at some point, there's not much that will help the answer stand on its own.

Comment: Agreed, but at least now it's a little more substantial an answer. Thanks for taking the time to enhance it!